# Complex DTO structure

Tags: .net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, data-transfer-objects

I've read a lot about DTO's here on SO, in books and articles, but I'm not sure if I get it right.

We're using DTO's in our project so that they're almost just properties of Domain Objects. For that reason, we need to have a complex DTO structure. There're some classes extending one another, compositions, aggregate, etc. .

Question is more general.

Is it right to inherit a dto from another one or to have a reference on a dto in another dto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it right to inherit a DTO from another one

If they share common properties, then why not?

> have a reference in a DTO to another DTO

There is definitely nothing wrong with this, consider the following:

```
public class UserDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDto
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Remember DTO's are simply *dumb* objects i.e. they have no behaviour (other than getting/setting their own data). The same rules apply to DTO's as they would for standard classes/objects from an architectural point of view, so there is no reason why you shouldn't be following the same principles if and when you can.

Comment: I thought, that I should keep dto's as simple as I can, so for example instead of storing reference to another dto, I should store it's properties. In UserDto I would have addressline1, addressline2 and city, considering that I would use dto's with WCF.

Comment: I've read that there're some problems with complex DTO's used in WCF Service. For example, circular references.

Comment: @hgulyan You can of course do that if you want, however, that sort of design doesn't sit well with me. Having properties which are DTO objects themselves is prefectly acceptable (I would say preferred). WCF should handle serialization just fine. "*I've read that they're some problems with complex DTO's... circular references*" that's someone elses implementation and issues with a model with no doubt different complexity. You need to at least *try* it first before you decide it's not going to work.

Comment: If I got you right, you mean, I can use DTO objects as I wish, the main restriction is not to store behavior, right?

Comment: @hgulyan the purpose of a DTO is to simply transfer data between different layers of your application e.g. Business Layer -> Data Access Layer. "*the main restriction is not to store behaviour*" yes DTO's shouldn't have any business logic behaviour, they are simply data retainers.

Comment: @hgulyan your welcome :) If your mapping a lot of of data you should have a look at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: Thanks for that too. I've read about it and tried for simple mappings. Very helpful tool :)

Answer (score 0):

DTO is for inter-layer communication.

I prefer simple DTOs because they are used mainly to tell the persistence layer, generally speaking Data Access Objects, what to store. If that's the case, don't go for complex DTOs.

If DTOs are complex (i.e. a DTO having another DTO as attribute), the complexity required for the DAO to store the data is greater. This conflicts the goal of DAO to be the way to decouple from storage technology.

So, if a DTO needs to address another DTO, just use string ids as attributes and keep a simple DAO for each DTO. Logic to handle interconnected DTOs should go to the Service Application or Business Object making use of the DAOs. This way, you increase reuse of the code.