# Data transfer object class can contain other objects?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I just wanted to know DTO class contain another objects or not. Please tell me the below code is valid DTO class or not?

```
class Address implements Serializable{

private String city;
private String location

}

class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable{
private String name;
private int age;
private Address address;
//setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex DTO structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667377/complex-dto-structure)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> DTO - Data transfer objects are just data containers which are used to
> transport data between layers and tiers. It mainly contains
> attributes. You can even use public attributes without getters and
> setters. Data transfer objects do not contain any business logic.

Yes I think that they are valid DTO's but without business logic. The main purpose of DTO is they hold values to be used in other layers of the design of the system.

A plus to remember, DTO's have no other behavior other than the `getters` and `setters` of the attributes.